# Manipulação de Arquivo TXT usando Python

Tags: python

Digamos que eu tenha um `arquivo.txt` que está separando as informações somente pela virgula, por exemplo,

```
X,Y,Z,W         
1,2,3,4
```

Como faço para modificar tal arquivo e salvar de forma que fique uma tabela sem a presença dessas virgulas (veja a ilustração a seguir)?

```
X Y Z W         
1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos lá, o primeiro passo é manipular o arquivo TXT. Para isso, da uma olhadinha nesse link: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python

Com isso, a lógica para implementação é seguir os seguintes passos:

1. Ler as linhas do arquivo;
2. Substituir os caracteres `,` (vígula) por  (espaço em branco) e armazená-los em uma variável;
3. Escrever o texto armazenado na variável no mesmo arquivo.

Implementando a lógica:

```
fileRead = open("arquivo.txt","r")

textoNovoArquivo = ''
for line in fileRead:
    textoNovoArquivo += line.replace(","," ")

fileRead.close()

fileWrite = open("/home/enio/python/arquivo.txt","w")

fileWrite.write(textoNovoArquivo)

fileWrite.close()
```

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Prezado Enio Costa, o seu código funcionou. Muito obrigado pela sua disposição. Espero chegar em um nível que eu possa retribuir ajudando as demais pessoas com suas dúvidas. Um forte abraço.

Comment: Esta resposta usa técnicas que não são recomendadas para arquivos grandes: ela carrega os dados do arquivo todo em memória e usa concatenação de strings para isso. Neste caso recomenda-se ler os dados bloco a bloco (e não linha a linha) e gravá-los em um arquivo secundário ou temporário a medida que os dados forem lidos.